Is there a matrix that has the completely opposite effect of a Hadamard matrix?
First, let me provide some background on the problem:
In the field of Large Language Model quantization/compressions, outliers (abs of outliers are much larger than the mean of abs of all elements in the matrix) in weights and activations can affect the precision of quantization. As a result, various methods have been proposed to enhance quantized model's accuracy, one of which is Rotation. Typically, we choose a randomized Hadamard matrix $Q$. For an operation during inference of LLM, $Y=XW$(X is activation and W is weight matrix), we transform it to $Y=XQ* Q^TW$ to maintain computational invariance. At the same time, $Q$ and $Q^T$ serves to suppress outliers in $W$ and $X$.
My question is:

Does there exist a similar matrix $P$, $Y=XP*P^TW$

such that:

$P$ maintains computational invariance,  $Y=XP*P^TW=XW$
$P^T$ suppresses the values of non-outliers or non-salient values in $W$ (making them closer to zero or turning to zero at all)**.




If not exists, is there a approximate matrix $O$, such that $Y\approx Y'=XO*O^TW$. $O$ reserves as much information from $W$ as possible and achieves the same effect as $P$


According to my intuitive understanding, when non-outliers or non-salient values in $W$ is transformed to zero(or closer to zero), the information of these values is absorbed by outliers or salient values in $W$. Outliers may be amplified. After rotated by $Q$, $W$ can be pruned. Non-outliers or non-salient values in $W$ can be turned to zero directly and keep other outliers or salient values (or change slightly) to compress $W$ without losing much information.
We only care about $W$. Outliers is distributed unstructurally in $W$. But in LLM area, outliers may be grouped in some rows or columns. So we can make some assumptions here, or not. Sparsity ratio is usually 30%~70%. Assumptions can be made freely here. I will find out whether LLM scenario  aligns with these assumptions.

the way multiplication by the orthogonal matrix $Q$ removes the outliers is by averaging; this can be done without any information on where the outliers are; if you instead want to amplify the outliers the orthogonal matrix $P$ would need that information (where are the outliers?), so I don't see how that could be done in an $X$-independent way.

We hava a validation dataset. So just assuming we have the whole information of W and X. We have enough samples of X.

I think the answer is no and here is my thought process:
We want a rotation matrix $R$ such that the elements in $RW$ are peakier in distribution (ie a column in $W$ with an outlier becomes more well aligned well with one of the bases).
Let's name the column of $W$ with the outlier $w$ and it aligns well with basis $e_i$ such that $w = e_i + \varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon$ is a random vector of small magnitude uniform around $0$.
We want $Rw$ to align more well with $e_j$ such that:
$$(e_j \cdot Rw) - (e_i \cdot w) > 0$$
Let's follow that train of thought:
$$(e_j \cdot R(e_i + \varepsilon)) - (e_i \cdot (e_i + \varepsilon)) > 0$$
$$e_j \cdot R(e_i + \varepsilon) - e_i \cdot e_i - e_i \cdot \varepsilon > 0$$
$$R_{j,\cdot}e_i + R_{j,\cdot}\varepsilon - 1 - \varepsilon_i > 0$$
$$R_{j, i} + R_{j, \cdot}\varepsilon - \varepsilon_i > 1$$
$\mathbb E (R_{j, \cdot} \varepsilon) = 0$ because $\varepsilon$ is random around 0.
$\mathbb E (\varepsilon_i) = 0$ because $\varepsilon$ is random around 0.
$$\mathbb E (R_{j, \cdot}e_i + R_{j, \cdot}\varepsilon - \varepsilon_i) = R_{j,i}$$
This leads to a contradiction because $R_{j,i} \leq 1$ because $R$ is a rotation matrix, so we can not have $R_{j,i} > 1$
The intuition for coming up with this answer is that almost no vectors align with the bases as the number of dimensions increases, so a matrix having the property that it makes random vectors more aligned with the bases didn't sit right.

My apologies, I might not have been clear with some information.  We are more focused here on how to weaken $\varepsilon$ or making its value approach zero.  So that we can prune $W$ ( keep outlies or change them, but turn other values to zero, the sparsity may be 50% around).

To align $Rw$  better with basis $e_j$ is not our purpose. And $e_j$ can be the same with $e_i$. I simply believe that if other variables are brought closer to zero, then the remaining outliers will absorb this information, making their values more prominent. It's just my intuitive understanding, not derived from a formal deduction.

I'm pretty sure my same thought process still works with 50% sparcity of $w$.
In that case, we have an n-dimentional vector $v = \delta(i<\frac{n}{2}) + \varepsilon_i = [1+\varepsilon_0,1+\varepsilon_2,...,\varepsilon_{n-1},\varepsilon_n]$ and we want to find a rotation $R$ such that $Rv \approx [1,1,...,0,0]$ such that
$$Rv \cdot [1,1,...,0,0] - v \cdot [1,1,...,0,0] > 0$$
Is this a correct interpretation? We have $\frac n2$ outliers of the form $(1+\varepsilon)$ and $\frac n2$ small numbers of the form $\varepsilon$ and we want to 0 out the noise $\varepsilon$ as much as possible?

Because, when we could follow the train of thought:
$${R([1,1,...,0,0]+\varepsilon) - ([1,1,...,0,0]+\varepsilon)} \cdot [1,1,...,0,0] > 0$$
$$R[1,1,...,0,0] \cdot [1,1,...,0,0] + R \varepsilon \cdot [1,1,...,0,0] - \varepsilon \cdot [1,1,...,0,0] > \frac n2 $$
$$\mathbf E(R[1,1,...,0,0] \cdot [1,1,...,0,0] + R \varepsilon \cdot [1,1,...,0,0] - \varepsilon \cdot [1,1,...,0,0]) = R[1,1,...,0,0] \cdot [1,1,...,0,0] \leq \frac n2$$

If we have round($W$) is of the form [[0,1,0,0,...],[1,1,0,0,...],...]=$\hat W$, and you want to even out the noise, maybe you could use something like:
$$Wv = (\hat W + \varepsilon)v$$
And you could use random hadimard matrixes to remove the biggest values from the $\varepsilon$ matrix and make it closer to 0? Like:
$$Wv = (\hat W + \varepsilon)v = H^{-1} (H \hat W v+ H \varepsilon v)$$
?

Why we have $Rv\cdot [1,1,\ldots,0,0]-v\cdot[1,1,\ldots,0,0]\gt 0$?
Is it a assumption or intuitive understanding? When we turn non-outliers to zeros, do outliers align better on their base direction? Some theoretical support?

That was what my interpretation of the goal. We want W = [1.1,0.9,0.1,0.1]/(1.1^2+0.9^2+0.1^2+0.1^2)^0.5 to turn into W = [1,1,0,0]/2^0.5 because that is what turning non-outliers to 0 would mean in practice (for a normalized weight matrix where the outliers are the same order of magnitude).
